# Executar comando com variável -JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Bom dia ,

Em uma pagina , tenho algumas div ao qual coloquei um efeito para elas aparecerem (toogle)
Eu gostaria que esse efeito fosse alternado sempre que eu executasse sua respectiva funcao.

Então, descobri essa funcao que embaralha o conteudo de um array

```
function embaralhar_efeito(o){
        for(var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
        return o[0]; //retorna somente o 1 valor.
    }

    var array_efeitos = ['slideToggle','slideDown','slideUp','fadeToggle','fadeTo','fadeIn'];
    var efeito_toogle = embaralhar_efeito(array_efeitos);
```

Assim , passo o resultado para a funcao que faria o toogle na minha div:

```
function efeito_pergunta(efeito){

        var modifica = '$("#div_pergunta").';
        var modifica_2 = efeito+'(3000);';

        var acao = modifica + modifica_2;
    }
```

Quando do um alert(acao) , ele retorna $("#div_pergunta").slideDown(3000);//aqui , o efeito(slideDown) vai alterando conforme executa a funcao embaralhar_efeito.
Mas a div não recebe o efeito do toogle.

Tem como executar o codigo desta maneira  ?

Desde ja, grato

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em vez de transformar todo metodo do jquery em uma string e salvar em uma variavel você pode executar direto apenas passando como uma propriedade de um objeto:

```js
function embaralhar_efeito(o) {
  for (var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
  return o[0]; //retorna somente o 1 valor.
}
var array_efeitos = ['slideToggle', 'slideDown', 'slideUp', 'fadeToggle', 'fadeTo', 'fadeIn'];
var efeito_toogle = embaralhar_efeito(array_efeitos);
efeito_pergunta(efeito_toogle);

function efeito_pergunta(efeito) {
  $("#div_pergunta")[efeito]('3000');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div_pergunta">Conteudo aqui</div>
```

Comment: Boa tarde , muito obrigado  , deu certinho aqui.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode utilizar `[]` para acessar propriedades e métodos de um objeto a partir do valor de uma variável.

```
function efeito_pergunta(efeito) {
   $('#div_pergunta')[efeito](300);
}
```

[Veja aqui um exemplo funcionando](https://jsfiddle.net/4mmvxk56/)

Answer (score 1):

Experimenta o seguinte:

```
function efeito_pergunta(efeito){
    var modifica = '$("#div_pergunta").';
    var modifica_2 = efeito+'(3000);';
    var acao = modifica + modifica_2;
    eval(acao);
}
```